# Passing a file descriptor opened in C to a tcl interpreter for use

Tags: tcl

I have a C program in which I create a tcl interpreter. I then open a file in the C program and want to pass it onto the tcl interpreter so the tcl interpreter can do I/O on it.

And I realize I could just open the file in the tcl interpreter, but I get an open file descriptor some somewhere else, so that's not an option, unfortunately.

Any ideas or tricks, or did I miss something in the tcl C API?

Answer (score 1):

```
man Tcl_MakeFileChannel
```

Read there about `Tcl_MakeFileChannel` and `Tcl_RegisterChannel`

Comment: I saw chan command doc at tcl level, but I didn't see anything that appeared appropriate for doing this. I simplified the problem. Actually, I am using the Perl Tcl module and need to construct a tcl command to do the same thing. Is there an equivalent way to do this via the tcl "chan" operation? Because file is opened in Perl, but I can access file descriptor, and need to connect this into the tcl subsystem. But if there isn't, I'll bite the bullet and do it in C this way. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Could you write a TCL C extension to create a new TCL command that does what you need using the Tcl_MakeFileChannel and Tcl_RegisterChannel API functions?

Comment: I do think these tips are the way you need to go. Tcl_MakeFileChannel takes an existing file handle and makes it available in Tcl. Read the documentation thoroughly. I have not worked with combining Perl and Tcl, so I can't give any specific tips for that.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't have have to open the file *before* you create the tcl interpreter process, if it's going to have the file descriptor have meaning?

If you open after, and say in the C program you have file descriptor 9, and you then pass this 9 to the tcl interpreter process, that 9's not going to mean anything.

Comment: This comment would apply if he was running Tcl as a separate process, but I think he has a Tcl interpreter embedded in the C program, ie. in the same process.